# How can I make awk on Busybox treat the entire input with NULL character in between as a single record?

Tags: shell, scripting, awk, busybox, binary

I wrote a base64 encode script for my Busybox system.

```
#!/bin/sh
base64encode()
{
/usr/bin/awk -- '
function asc(char,l_found)
{
        l_found=0;
        for (i=0;i<=255;i++){
        if (sprintf("%c",i)==char) l_found=i;
        }
        return l_found;
}

function base64_and(var,x,l_res,l_i)
{
        l_res=0;
        for (l_i=0;l_i<8;l_i++){
                if (var%2==1 && x%2==1) l_res=l_res/2+128;
                else l_res/=2;
                       var=int(var/2);
                x=int(x/2);
        }
        return l_res;
}

function base64_lshift(var,x)
{
        while(x>0){
        var*=2;
        x--;
        }
        return var;
}

function base64_rshift(var,x)
{
        while(x>0){
        var=int(var/2);
        x--;
        }
        return var;
}

BEGIN{
BASE64="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";
result="";
}

{
        while (length($0)>0){
printf "Source: %s Length: %i\n",$0,length($0);
                if (length($0)==1){
                        byte1=asc(substr($0,1,1));
                        byte2=0;
                        byte3=0;
                }

                if (length($0)==2){
                        byte1=asc(substr($0,1,1));
                        byte2=asc(substr($0,2,1));
                        byte3=0;
                }

                if (length($0)>=3){
                        byte1=asc(substr($0,1,1));
                        byte2=asc(substr($0,2,1));
                        byte3=asc(substr($0,3,1));
                }

                base1=base64_rshift(byte1,2);
                base2=base64_lshift(base64_and(byte1,3),4)+base64_rshift(base64_and(byte2,240),4);
                base3=base64_lshift(base64_and(byte2,15),2)+base64_rshift(base64_and(byte3,192),6);
                base4=base64_and(byte3,63);
printf "byte1=%i byte2=%i byte3=%i\n", byte1, byte2, byte3;
printf "base1=%i base2=%i base3=%i base4=%i\n", base1, base2, base3, base4;
                if (length($0)==1){
                        result=result substr(BASE64,base1+1,1);
                        result=result substr(BASE64,base2+1,1);
                        result=result "==";
                        $0="";
                }

                if (length($0)==2){
                        result=result substr(BASE64,base1+1,1);
                        result=result substr(BASE64,base2+1,1);
                        result=result substr(BASE64,base3+1,1);
                        result=result "=";
                        $0="";
                }

                if (length($0)>=3){
                        result=result substr(BASE64,base1+1,1);
                        result=result substr(BASE64,base2+1,1);
                        result=result substr(BASE64,base3+1,1);
                        result=result substr(BASE64,base4+1,1);
                        $0=substr($0,4);
                }
printf "Result=%s\n", result;
        }

        printf "%s",result;
}
'
}
base64encode
```

But when there are NULL characters in the input, awk will seperate the input into different records and make the script output incorrectly.

For example:

```
root@unknown:/tmp/test# echo -e "Hello \0 World!"|./base64encode.sh
Source: Hello  Length: 6
byte1=72 byte2=101 byte3=108
base1=18 base2=6 base3=21 base4=44
Result=SGVs
Source: lo  Length: 3
byte1=108 byte2=111 byte3=32
base1=27 base2=6 base3=60 base4=32
Result=SGVsbG8g
SGVsbG8gSource:  World! Length: 7
byte1=32 byte2=87 byte3=111
base1=8 base2=5 base3=29 base4=47
Result=SGVsbG8gIFdv
Source: rld! Length: 4
byte1=114 byte2=108 byte3=100
base1=28 base2=38 base3=49 base4=36
Result=SGVsbG8gIFdvcmxk
Source: ! Length: 1
byte1=33 byte2=0 byte3=0
base1=8 base2=16 base3=0 base4=0
Result=SGVsbG8gIFdvcmxkIQ==
SGVsbG8gIFdvcmxkIQ==root@unknown:/tmp/test#
```

While from Linux, we can tell the output was not correct because the above input was divided into two records and the NULL character in between is not processed.

```
[root@hp8 ~]# echo -e "Hello \0 World\!"|base64
SGVsbG8gACBXb3JsZFwhCg==
[root@hp8 ~]#
```

Can anyone please tell me how I can make the awk on my Busybox treat the entire input with NULL character in between as a single record?

Comment: Does your install include `sed` or `tr`? I usually see solutions where the null characters are converted first using either of those tools. LMK and I can write up a solution if you have either of these tools.

Comment: Yes, I have both sed and tr on my Busybox system. but sed on Busybox might also have problem with null characters, like the below command won't work. echo -e "Hello my World"|sed 's/my/\0x00/' The output is "Hello myx00 World".

Comment: Try `tr '\0' ''`.

Comment: Yes, tr '\0' ' ' can replace null character with space character, but my purpose is not to remove the null characters from the input but to keep the input unchanged and handled by the base64 encode script. The problem is awk takes the null character as recode seperater even the actual record seperater is not null character and seperates the input into pieces and makes the output incorrect.

Comment: Yes I understand your issue, I've usually seen it dealt with in this manner of swapping them out. I'll see if I can find another method.

Comment: Thank you very much. If it is not convenient to put your solution here in the comment area, please send me a mail at syu2000@gmail.com.

Comment: See the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your BusyBox installation has the [`uuencode`](http://busybox.net/downloads/BusyBox.html#uuencode) utility, forget all this and use `uuencode -m`.

```
base64encode () {
  uuencode -m ignored | tail -n +2
}
```

If you really need to use awk, I think it just can't cope with null bytes. A possible workaround is to first translate the null bytes into something else, for example with judicious applications of `tr` and `sed`. `tr` supports null bytes as it should, and sed can't manipulate them directly but does pass them through. While you're at it, translate newlines too, otherwise I think you won't be able to tell whether the input file ended in a newline or not.

```
sed -e 's/[a-z]/q&/g' | tr '\0\n' zn | awk …
```

In the input to the awk script:

- there are no null bytes or newlines;
- all lowercase letters standing for themselves have a `q` before them;
- `z` stands for a null byte and `n` stands for a newline.

Comment: `uuencode` in BusyBox requires a `STORED_FILENAME` argument.

Answer (score 0):

I did not test this exhaustively but I believe you can set the variable `ORS` to `\0` which should get Busybox's `awk` to stop splitting on NULL's.

#### Example

*without*

```
$ echo -e "Hello \0 World\!" | busybox awk '{print $1}'
Hello
World\!
```

*with*

```
$ echo -e "Hello \0 World\!" | busybox awk -vORS=$'\0' '{print $1}'
HelloWorld\!
```

Notice it didn't split on anything, so the entire string is contained in the `$1` variable within `awk`.

#### Details

The variable `ORS` within `awk` is the output record separator.

*excerpt from awk man page*

```
   ORS         The output record separator, by default a newline.
   ...
   print       Print the current record.  The output record is terminated 
               with the value of the  ORS variable.
```

Comment: Yes, by that awk didn't split the original input, but the null character is gone. I want to keep the input unchanged and handled by the base64 encode script. `root@unknown:/tmp/test# echo -e "Hello \0 World\!" | busybox awk -vORS=$'\0' '{print $1}'|hexdump -C 00000000 48 65 6c 6c 6f 57 6f 72 6c 64 5c 21 |HelloWorld\!| 0000000c root@unknown:/tmp/test#`